# Problem with binomial coefficients and their symmetry

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm going through my workbook and ran across this:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{4n}{4k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{4n}{4k+1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{4n}{4(n-k-1)-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{4n}{2k+1}$$
The first thing that bothers me is why does: $$\binom{4n}{4k+1}=\binom{4n}{4(n-k-1)-1}$$
The second thing that bothers me is why the sum of those equals:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{4n}{2k+1}$$

Comment: The fist is just a relabeling $k-> n-k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that ${4n\choose4(n-k-1)-1}$ should be ${4n\choose4(n-k)-1}$.  That is the basic symmetry of binomial coefficients, that ${4n\choose x}={4n\choose 4n-x}$.
The second thing: the first sum includes all odd numbers that are 1 more than a multiple of 4; the second sum includes all odd numbers that are 1 less than a multiple of 4.  Together, they include all odd numbers below $4n$.